# spring properties - structure

Tags: spring, groovy

I've got a scenario where I have the following type of data that I want to specify in my properties file.

To describe it I have a domain, each which can have a type and subtype.

```
wallet.items.domain=APPLE,DOMAIN_TWO

wallet.domain.types.apple=TYPE_ONE, PAYPAL
wallet.domain.subtypes.apple=SUB_TYPE_ONE

wallet.domain.types.paypal=TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO, TYPE_THREE
wallet.domain.subtypes.paypal=SUB_TYPE_ONE, SUB_TYPE_TWO, SUB_TYPE_THREE, SUB_TYPE_FOUR
```

I want to validate that the types and the subtypes for a domain are valid in a generic manner. For example these are valid combinations.

APPLE, TYPE_ONE, SUB_TYPE_ONE
APPLE, TYPE_TWO, SUB_TYPE_ONE
APPLE, TYPE_TWO, SUB_TYPE_ONE
PAYPAL,TYPE_ONE,SUB_TYPE_ONE

My first challenge is to structure this in a properties file such that I can use them in a validate routine in groovy generically.

I'm using spring for property file mnmgt.

Can anyone help me with a nice generic way to do this?

Comment: have you thought of keeping this in a database? I think, it is much more manageable way when the list will grow

Comment: Yeah I suggested this to a colleague but wanted to find out whether there are any clever ways to do it from a properties file.